# Java memory collection usage

Tags: java

I have a try catch and finally block like this.

```
Client client = new Client();
try {
   ...
}
catch {
   ...
}
finally {
   client = null;
}
```

I would like to ask if `client = null` is necessary to wipe out memory use for client object if exception occurs.

Comment: @JoopEggen - Would a problem occur if you did that anyway (i.e. type `client = null;` ) ?

Comment: @delnan Who would've explained it? And it is hard to search if you don't know what the relevant keywords are.

Comment: @biziclop Whoever is teaching people Java ought to explain it at some point, I'd say. And searching for `java memory null variable` on StackOverflow has 4 relevant question in the first 50 results (just skimmed over the titles, didn't take very long) - I suppose other combinations fare well too. I alone have seen this questions dozens of times, and I'm sure I didn't see them all.

Comment: No, you can set client to null anyway. But in fact that probably is the last occurrence of `client` so it might even postpone the garbage collection up to that statement. Does not matter, but if before `finally` there is some huge allocation.

Comment: @delnan Why do you assume anyone is teaching them Java? Many people are self-taught. SO is full of redundant questions anyway, one more won't make an inch of a difference.

Comment: @biziclop I include tutorials and other resources for self-learners (yeah, my fault for not including "/whatever"). And while redundant questions are an annoyance, I'm usually not complaining about them. However, some questions are asked so frequently that I'm stumped as to *why* (apparently) nobody finds that out without asking SO. I'm self-taught too, yet I could write you a whole essay on this issue.

Comment: Actually I myself believe a No as answer, but my friend keeps arguing that he has seen many people did that, so I ask this question to tell him that he's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever an object has no references to it **for any reason** then it becomes eligible for garbage collection, including if a variable goes out of scope as a result of the program leaving a function or statement block. In other words, no.

Comment: +1 for being the closest to explaining the underlying reasoning (rick.okelly speaks of references to a variable, which seems like confusing nonsense). Throw in some discussion on **reachability** and it'd be even better :)

Answer (score 4):

As soon as the `client` variable is no longer reachable (ie no longer has a [GC root](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html)) it is eligible for garbage collection.

In your example it appears as if `client` will be unreachable as soon as the method exits (whether by an exception being thrown or a 'normal' return), so assigning it to null is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Client object is subject to scope.If Client object has class scope then it will live until class will load, if client has method scope then it will live until control will be inside method.

there are many scopes besides these two.

so need not to wipe out object. You only need to wipe out when some resource are used like File IO or Database connection.

Answer (score 1):

No, Java's garbage collector [takes care of this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html).

I would tattoo this on my forehead, as this is one of Java's big strengths in relation to C/C++.

Comment: "Java's biggest selling point" - That's silly; lots of languages have equally or similarly good garbage collection, have more features, and are in general easier to use. C# and Python come to mind.

Comment: The revised version will just piss the C++ developers off (at least the decent ones who know to use smart pointers). Just take that whole "GC is the best thing since sliced bread" part out, it contributes nothing.

Comment: @delnan - Garbage collection is a *strength* , I hereby summon all JavaBeans!

Comment: I prefer it too, but your subjective opinion on it has no place in an answer. You could try turning it into a list of objective reasons GC is a strength, but that'd be off topic ;)